# Why does $|T^{*}T|\geq |T|^2$ hold for the operator norm?

Tags: functional-analysis

I'd like to know how to prove that $|T^{*}T|=|T|^2$. I know that is $\leq$ since $|T|=|T^{*}|$ but I don't know how to prove the reverse inequality. Thanks.

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your question more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.*

Comment: Here's a pointer to Dana Williams' $C^*$ script:
https://math.dartmouth.edu/~dana/bookspapers/cstar.pdf#page=36

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to icurays1's solution, where you need to know that the first equality in his proof holds, here is a direct way:

$$\|Tx\|^2=\langle Tx,Tx\rangle=\langle T^*Tx,x\rangle\leq \|T^*T\|\, \|x\|^2$$

Then
$$
\|T\|^2=\sup\{\|Tx\|^2:\ \|x\|=1\}\leq\|T^*T\|
$$

Answer (score 1):

We can prove equality directly by noticing that $T^*T$ is a self adjoint operator, and thus

$$
\|T^*T\|=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\vert\langle x,T^*Tx\rangle\vert=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\vert \langle Tx,Tx\rangle\vert=\|T\|^2
$$